# Json normalizing with pandas json_normalize for dynamic records and inner arrays

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following problems: I am reading records from mongo collection, which are in fact json records, for example the following (test) record:

```
d = {"accounts" : [{"Email" : [{"testclass1":"6b296577-d437-4209-9e91-2fd67b5e7f1e@gmail.com","testclass2" : "6b296577-d437-4209-9e91-2fd67b5e7f1e__PI_1_1","testclass3" : "6b296577-d437-4209-9e91-2fd67b5e7f1e__PI_1_1"}],"bank_id" : "test14-bank","views_available" : [{"is_public" : "True","short_name" : "HHH","id" : "1"}],"Data_Type_test_Boolean" : "True","Data_Type_test_Number" : "44444444","pi_values" : ["6b296577-d437-4209-9e91-2fd67b5e7f1e@gmail.com","6b296577-d437-4209-9e91-2fd67b5e7f1e__PI_1_1","6b296577-d437-4209-9e91-2fd67b5e7f1e__PI_1_1"],"id" : "e01e1118-6143-428d-881c-b04a20b54076","label" : "My account label","sensitivity" : "sensitivity_data"}]}
```

Problem #1:

I want to ultimately receive a **completely flattened** pandas dataframe with columns such as: account.Email.testclass1, .., accounts.views_available.is_public...

I tried:

```
>> pd.json_normalize(d,record_path="accounts").columns
>> Index: Index(['Email', 'bank_id', 'views_available', 'Data_Type_test_Boolean',
       'Data_Type_test_Number', 'pi_values', 'id', 'label', 'sensitivity',
       'accounts'],
      dtype='object')
```

but it does not suffice, as it misses the entire accounts.views_available.is_public hierarchy, which is in-fact an inner-array object.
I search quite a lot and did not find any way to handle this scenario.

Is there a way to pass in a **one-line** to the json_normalize function all the record_paths ("outer" and "inner") that are necessary for the result I need?

I am aware of solutions such as suggested here [Normalizing json list as values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342490/normalizing-json-list-as-values), yet wondering if there is a cleaner (as in fewer-lines) option.

Problem #2:

As described, I am reading multiple records from a mongo collection to a dataframe, where the json structure from one record to another may change. That is, the dict `d` as in the example may have a different structure in a different record (part of the reason for representing as a json...).
Ideally, I would like to be able to use json_normalize function on the entire mongo-records dataframe (and provide it with a list of dictionaries), but since the json structure may vary across records, i'm not sure its feasible.

Any advice will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a one-liner for json_normalize() is going to cut it, unfortunately. It's not clear what would change from one record to the next. This particular record has this structure:

```
list(d['accounts'][0].keys())
['Email',
 'bank_id',
 'views_available',
 'Data_Type_test_Boolean',
 'Data_Type_test_Number',
 'pi_values',
 'id',
 'label',
 'sensitivity']
```

where Email and views_available are both dictionaries, but pi_values is a list which if flattened takes more work to get into one line. You can play around with the following to see if anything sticks.

```
dfe = pd.json_normalize(d['accounts'], record_path=['Email'],
    meta=['bank_id', 'Data_Type_test_Boolean', 'Data_Type_test_Number', 'id', 'label', 'sensitivity'],
    record_prefix='accounts.Email.')
print(dfe)

dfv = pd.json_normalize(d['accounts'], record_path=['views_available'],
    record_prefix='accounts.views_available.')
print(dfv)

df = pd.json_normalize(d['accounts'], record_path=['pi_values'],
    record_prefix='accounts.pi_values.').T.reset_index(drop=True)
new_cols = ['accounts.pi_values.'+str(v) for v in dfp.columns.tolist()]
df.columns = new_cols
print(df)

df_final = pd.concat([dfe, dfv, df], axis=1)
print(df_final)
```

Column names in final flattened dataframe

```
Index(['accounts.Email.testclass1', 'accounts.Email.testclass2',
       'accounts.Email.testclass3', 'bank_id', 'Data_Type_test_Boolean',
       'Data_Type_test_Number', 'id', 'label', 'sensitivity',
       'accounts.views_available.is_public',
       'accounts.views_available.short_name', 'accounts.views_available.id',
       'accounts.pi_values.0', 'accounts.pi_values.1', 'accounts.pi_values.2'],
      dtype='object')
```